# Need help understanding range between in SQL window functions

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, window-functions

I am trying understand how range clause is working in below case (oracle database)

```
SELECT
    EMPID,NAME, 
    HIRE_DATE_1, 
    SALARY,
    count(1) over(order by HIRE_DATE_1 range between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as PREV_MIN_SA
FROM (
    SELECT 
        EMPID,
        NAME,
        (EXTRACT(year from HIRE_DATE)*10000)+(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) * 100) + (extract(DAY from HIRE_DATE)) as HIRE_DATE_1,SALARY
     FROM EMPLOYEE A order by HIRE_DATE,SALARY
) A
ORDER BY HIRE_DATE_1
```

Result Set :

```
EMPID   NAME    HIRE_DATE_1 SALARY  PREV_MIN_SA
100     Ravi    20180101    5000    0
101     Kumar   20180101    7000    0
102     Satish  20180101    13000   0
103     Naresh  20180102    7500    3
105     Lalith  20180104    17300   0
104     Suresh  20180104    40000   0
106     Latha   20180201    16000   0
```

The inner query is just converting date into numeric YYYYMMDD format.
My intention is to get the count of people who joined immediately prior to the date of the employee in each record. I can take the count of rows with same HIRE_DATE and use LAG function but somehow not understand how the sql is returning this result set.

Also, once I am done with the counts I would like to get the MIN(SALARY) of the employees who joined immediately prior to the employee in current row and find the difference in salaries so wondering if somehow I can define the window to only have all records with immediately prior HIRE_DATE.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: That counts the number of rows where the `HIRE_DATE_1` is exactly one less than the current row's `HIRE_DATE_1`.  Because you went to the effort of converting the date to an integer, it will "break" on month boundaries and year boundaries.  Why did you convert the data to an integer!?

Comment: I am using Oracle Live SQL (online) so not sure what version it runs at the background

Comment: @MatBailie : I was thinking "range with 1 preceding " would refer to the value prior  in the ordered set instead of exactly 1 minus. I converted to integer as I was more comfortable with integer arithmetic than deal with timestamps (oracle seems to capture timestamps in date datatypes)

Comment: `RANGE BETWEEN` seems to vary from vendor to vendor :( Oracle uses "current row value - x"

Comment: @MatBailie : True, I tried in teradata and found it does not support Range Clause then tried Netezza and it gave an error if I try to define a window that does not include the current row. Then I tried Oracle and for your point on dealing with Dates directly, it would also do exactly - 1 and not solve the intent :(

Comment: [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com) is currently at version 18.0.0.0.0 (based on a query of `v$version`).

Answer (score 1):

This should get the preceding hire date...

```
SELECT
    EMPID,NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY,
    MAX(HIRE_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY HIRE_DATE
                            RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                      AND INTERVAL '1 DAY' PRECEDING
                        )
                           AS PREV_HIRE_DATE
FROM
    EMPLOYEE
```

Then I think you need to join back on to the employee table to find the number of employees and their min salary?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        EMPID,NAME, HIRE_DATE, SALARY,
        MAX(HIRE_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY HIRE_DATE
                                RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND INTERVAL '1 DAY' PRECEDING
                            )
                               AS PREV_HIRE_DATE
    FROM
        EMPLOYEE
)
    EMPS
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        HIRE_DATE,
        COUNT(*)     AS COUNT_EMPS,
        MIN(SALARY)  AS MIN_SALARY
    FROM
        EMPLOYEE
    GROUP BY
        HIRE_DATE
)
    PREV_EMPS
        ON PREV_EMPS.HIRE_DATE = EMPS.PREV_HIRE_DATE
```

***EDIT:***

Maybe try something like this?  *(I have to run, good luck!)*

```
WITH
  ranked AS
(
    SELECT
      *,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY HIRE_DATE)   AS HIRE_SEQ_ID
    FROM
      EMPLOYEE
)
SELECT
  *,
  MIN(SALARY) OVER (ORDER BY HIRE_SEQ_ID
                       RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                   )
                      AS PREV_MIN_SALARY,
  COUNT(*)    OVER (ORDER BY HIRE_SEQ_ID
                       RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                   )
                      AS COUNT_PREV_EMPS
FROM
  ranked
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're after, I believe (I've left it as an exercise for you to find the difference between the max and min salaries!):

```
WITH employee AS (SELECT 100 empid, 'Ravi' NAME, to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 5000 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 101 empid, 'Kumar' NAME, to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 7000 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 102 empid, 'Satish' NAME, to_date('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 13000 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 103 empid, 'Naresh' NAME, to_date('02/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 7500 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 104 empid, 'Lalith' NAME, to_date('04/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 17300 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 105 empid, 'Suresh' NAME, to_date('04/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 40000 salary FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 106 empid, 'Latha' NAME, to_date('01/02/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') hire_date, 16000 salary FROM dual)
SELECT empid,
       NAME,
       hire_date,
       salary,
       COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) prev_day_hire_count,
       MIN(salary) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) prev_day_min_sal,
       MAX(salary) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) prev_day_max_sal
FROM   employee;

     EMPID NAME   HIRE_DATE       SALARY PREV_DAY_HIRE_COUNT PREV_DAY_MIN_SAL PREV_DAY_MAX_SAL
---------- ------ ----------- ---------- ------------------- ---------------- ----------------
       100 Ravi   01/01/2018        5000                   0                  
       101 Kumar  01/01/2018        7000                   0                  
       102 Satish 01/01/2018       13000                   0                  
       103 Naresh 02/01/2018        7500                   3             5000            13000
       104 Lalith 04/01/2018       17300                   0                  
       105 Suresh 04/01/2018       40000                   0                  
       106 Latha  01/02/2018       16000                   0
```

Comment: The row with EMPID 104 should get PREV_DAY_MIN_SAL=7500. For this record the prior date is '02/01/2018' and there is only one record so consider 7500.